# how to use my own file instead of using dataset in this code

Tags: python, python-2.7, classification, naivebayes

i am implementing this code and this gives me the corrent output but i want to save those four lines of"dataset" in a file and then use it.how can i do this?how can i use my own file instead of manually typed dataset?

```
from naiveBayesClassifier import tokenizer

from naiveBayesClassifier.trainer import Trainer

from naiveBayesClassifier.classifier import Classifier

nTrainer = Trainer(tokenizer)


dataSet =[
    {'text': 'hello everyone', 'category': 'NO'},

    {'text': 'dont use words like jerk', 'category': 'YES'},

    {'text': 'what the hell.', 'category': 'NO'},

    {'text': 'you jerk','category': 'yes'},


]

for n in dataSet:

    nTrainer.train(n['text'], n['category'])

nClassifier = Classifier(nTrainer.data, tokenizer)
.
unknownInstance = "Even if I eat too much, is not it possible to lose some weight"

classification = nClassifier.classify(unknownInstance)

print classification
```

Answer (score 1):

You could store the data set as a json file and then load it in your python code:

```
import json


with open('data.json') as f:
    dataSet = json.loads(f.read())

    # Use dataset.
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\dtnbayes.py", line 17, in <module>
    dataSet = json.loads(f.read())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
ValueError: Expecting property name: line 2 column 6 (char 7)

Comment: Make sure you load a valid JSON. The single quotes need to be double quote for instance. You could use this: http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 0):

This line seems to be doing the most the work of training.

```
nTrainer.train(n['text'], n['category'])
```

This line seems to be doing the prediction after learning.

```
classification = nClassifier.classify(unknownInstance)
```

So if you a have a list of corpus (training data), a list of corresponding labels and list of data you want to predict (unknown instances)
You could so something like

```
from naiveBayesClassifier import tokenizer
from naiveBayesClassifier.trainer import Trainer
from naiveBayesClassifier.classifier import Classifier

corpus = ['hello everyone', 'dont use words like jerk', 'what the hell.', 'you jerk'] # Your training data
labels = ['NO', 'YES', 'NO', 'YES'] # Your labels
unknown_data = ['Even if I eat too much, is not it possible to lose some weight'] # List of data to be predicted

nTrainer = Trainer(tokenizer)

# model training
for item, category in zip(corpus, labels):
    nTrainer.train(item, category)

nClassifier = Classifier(nTrainer.data, tokenizer)
predictions = [ nClassifier.classify(unknownInstance)  for unknownInstance in unknown_data]

print classification
```